# by a quarter to ten

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

> I waited for him by a quarter to ten.

> I waited for him till a quarter to ten.

Is there any difference between the two sentences in their meanings?

What's the difference between 'by' and 'until'? Why past tense does not go well with 'by'?

Comment: The first one makes no sense.

Comment: Why? the only difference is 'by' and 'till' and that means by is not appropriate. 'I will finish the work 'by' Friday' is okay. Why not here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is incorrect.

The second one means:

> I waited for him up to the time of a quarter to ten, but at quarter to ten I left, and after that time I was no longer waiting for him.

The first one should be worded:

> I **was waiting** for him by a quarter to ten

and it means:

> When a quarter to ten came along, I was waiting for him.

So the first implies that I was still waiting for him *after* a quarter to ten, while the second asserts specifically that at a quarter to ten, I *stopped* waiting for him.

Comment: For use of *by a quarter to ten*: *He said that he would be there by quarter to ten.* (In GB English the "a" is often omitted)